# Want to create a file with write mode in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc

I am new in C. I want to create a file in linux C program and write environment variables in it. If file already exist I want to open and append. I have written the following code.

```
        char *envFile=getenv("FILENAME");   
        int fdEnv=-1;       
        fdEnv=open(envFile,O_CREAT,O_RDWR,O_APPEND);

        printf("%d",fdEnv);
        char** env;
        if(fdEnv>0)
        {
            for (env = environ; *env != 0; env++)
            {
                char *thisEnv = *env;       

                printf("%s",thisEnv);
                write(fdEnv,thisEnv,strlen(thisEnv));
            }
            close(fdEnv);

        }
```

But when I run it first time. A blank file is created. And it stays locked after execution. Looks like some error. Second time it fdEnv stays less than 0.

I really don't understand what is happening here. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `|` to separate the flags.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char **environ;
int main(void)
{
    char *envFile = getenv("FILENAME");
    int fdEnv = -1;
    fdEnv = open(envFile, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_APPEND, 0644);
    printf("%d\n", fdEnv);
    int i = 0;
    while (environ[i]) {
        printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
        write(fdEnv, environ[i], strlen(environ[i]));
        char lf = '\n';
        write(fdEnv, &lf, 1);
        i++;
    }
    close(fdEnv);
    return 0;
}
```

I've run above code on my linux computer and it works.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. But didn't work. Same problem. :(

Comment: Hello, It works great.Can you please explain the changes. I have some question. What is 0644 parameter in open? And please write you have passed 1 at the end after &lf ? Can you tell me what it does?

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, it is a good habit to always check the return value of system calls but I don't do it in the above code. I hope you can add such code to your program.

Comment: 0644 is the permission of the file. Check out http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Unix/unixpermissions.php

Comment: `write(fdEnv, &lf, 1);` adds a line feed ('\n') to the end of each line. `1` means the written string has length 1. Actually it's a single character.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    char **env;
    char* filename = getenv("FILENAME")

    const char* mode = "a";

    FILE* file = fopen( filename, mode );

    for ( env = environ; *env; ++env )
        fprintf( file, "%s\n", *env );

    fclose(file);

    return(0);
}
```

You should think about handling when getenv fails, is blank, etc; let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Regarding “let me know if you have any questions”, this is not how this site works. This is not a discussion forum. There is no back and forth. The only way for the OP to “let you know” would be to ask further questions as comments on your answer, which is discouraged, or worse, to edit the question and make all the answers that have already been provided and voted on bad answers. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tour , the way the principles there influence how this site work are not detailed but, to reiterate, this is not a discussion forum.